# Delete lines that match exactly and only a string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to delete lines that contain a certain string, for example "Cola", but only if the line matches exactly and has the same number of characters. In other words, don't delete lines with the word "Cola" inside but that are larger.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: `fgrep -xv Cola file`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '/^Cola$/d' < input
```

or

```
grep -Fxv Cola < input
```

or

```
awk '$0 != "Cola"' < input
```

Answer (score 0):

This the way to delete a line containing and only containing the string "Cola":

`cat somefile.txt | sed '/^Cola$/d' > newfile.txt`

Comment: You don't need to use the `cat` command there, the following would be enough `sed '/^Cola$/d' somefile.txt > newfile.txt`.

Comment: It's a bad kind of example.  Never do that.

Comment: Or use `--in-place` if it should just edit the same file: `sed -i '/^Cola$/d' file`. The example with fgrep does not delete lines, it filter out the match.

Comment: @hschou than you very much